# If I add some packages to "Recommends:", will apps pull them in with the update?

Tags: apt, update-manager, dpkg, packaging

I have a quesion about Debian packaging. I know that if I make a package depend on a larger number of packages then before, the newly introduced dependencies will be automatically downloaded by almost any package manager (only apt-get upgrade won't update the package at all). But what happens if I add some packages to "Recommends:" section? Will it be pulled in automatically? I'm particularly interested in behavior of Update Manager, Synaptic, apt-get upgrade, apt-get dselect-upgrade in Lucid and later Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Ubuntu (starting with Ubuntu 10.04 a.k.a. Lucid Lynx) installs packages listed in Recommends by default. However, this can be changed by the user at any time.